# how to use distinct() on filtered queries in Django?

Tags: python, django, filter, distinct

I have a query like this:

```
last_orders = PsSiparis.objects.filter(kullanici = request.user).order_by("-id")[:4]
for order in last_orders:
    print order.restoran
```

And it outputs:

```
Bafra Pide 
Bafra Pide 
Deneme Restoran 
Bafra Pide
```

I want to use distinct() attribute so my list will look like this:

```
Bafra Pide
Deneme Restoran
```

But I couldn't find the way. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `set`, which will remove duplicates:

```
>>> l = ['Bafra Pide','Bafra Pide','Deneme Restoran','Bafra Pide']
>>> s = set(l)
>>> for i in s:
...    print i
...
Bafra Pide
Deneme Restoran
```

You should add the individual names to the list and not the actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `.distinct()` on a sliced query since there's no simple way to generate the appropriate SQL query. You will need to postprocess using `set` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a method for selecting non equal results of a query. Give it a look:
[Django documentation, distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

edition: Also, limiting a Queryset returns a Queryset, so you are not gonna have problem with it, I would recommend slicing after applying distinc() method. [Limiting a Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

Comment: distinct() doesn't work in conjunction with .filter() - hence the OP's question (though he didn't word it very clearly).